# LDAP Images in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, authentication-authorization

I'm using the LDAP feeds module to import my users from LDAP to Drupal. However, it doesn't work... I'm only getting a lot of array merge errors (trying to merge a non-array object with an array in user_save), most likely because the picture is not imported properly and then attempted to merge with the current user.

The picture is in base64 in LDAP, attribute name 'jpegphoto'. In the LDAP feed, i have `jpegphoto.picture` as source, and `User Photo` as a target. Assuming that the base64 is the standard for pictures in LDAP and that pictures are supported - though not documented - i think there must be someone who knows how to import these pictures.